# bootstrap-vue b-table: keep expanded rows expanded on table reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, expand, persistent

the expand/collapse part of this works just fine.

Right now I am using javascript startInterval() to reload the table every 2 seconds.  Eventually this will be moving to web sockets.

In general, as part of the table load/reload, the system checks to see if it should display the icon " ^ " or " v " in the details column by checking row.detailsShowing, this works fine.

```
getChevron(row, index) {
 if (row.detailsShowing == true) {     
   return "chevronDown";
 }
   return "chevronUp";
}
```

When the user selects the " ^ " icon in the relationship column, `@click=row.toggleDetails` gets called to expand the row and then the function `v-on:click="toggleRow(row)"` is called to keep track of which row the user selected.  This uses a server side system generated guid to track.

Within 2 seconds the table will reload  and the row collapses.  On  load/reload, in the first column it loads, relationship,  I call a function checkChild(row), to check the row guid against my locally stored array, to determine if this is a row that should be expanded on load.

`<template #cell(relationship)="row"> {{checkChild(row)}} <\template>`

if the row guid matches one in the array I try setting

```
checkChild(row){
  var idx = this.showRows.indexOf( row.item.id);
    if(idx > -1){
     row.item.detailsShowing = true;
     row.rowSelected = true;
     row.detailsShowing == true
     row._showDetails = true;
   }
}
```

and I am able to see that i have found  match, but none of those variables set to true keeps the expanded row open, the row always collapses on reload

anyone have any ideas as to how i can make the row(s) stay open on table reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is because of a Vue 2 caveat. Adding properties to objects after they've been added to `data` will *not* be reactive. To get around this you have to utilize `Vue.set`.

You can read more about that [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

However, calling a function like you are doing in the template seems like bad practice.
You should instead do it after fetching your data, or use something like a computed property to do your mapping.

Here's two simplified examples.

#### Mapping after API call

```js
{
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      showRows: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://example.api')
      foreach(item of data) {
        const isRowExpanded = this.showRows.includes(item.id);
        item._showDetails = isRowExpanded;
      }
      this.items = data;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Using a computed

```js
{
  computed: {
    // Use `computedItems` in `<b-table :items="computedItems">`
    computedItems() {
      const { items, showRows } = this;
      return items.map(item => ({
        ...item, 
        _showDetails: .showRows.includes(item.id)
      }))
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      showRows: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://example.api')
      this.items = data;
    }
  }
}
```

For a more complete example, check the snippet below.

```js
const {
  name,
  datatype,
  image
} = faker;

const getUser = () => ({
  uuid: datatype.uuid(),
  personal_info: {
    first_name: name.firstName(),
    last_name: name.lastName(),
    gender: name.gender(),
    age: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 75) + 15
  },
  avatar: image.avatar()
});

const users = new Array(10).fill().map(getUser);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    computed_users() {
      const {
        expanded_rows,
        users
      } = this;
      return users.map((user) => ({
        ...user,
        _showDetails: expanded_rows[user.uuid]
      }));
    },
    total_rows() {
      const {
        computed_users
      } = this;
      return computed_users.length;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.users = users;

    setInterval(() => {
      users.push(getUser());
      this.users = [...users];
    }, 5000);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      per_page: 5,
      current_page: 1,
      users: [],
      fields: [{
          key: "avatar",
          class: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "name",
          thClass: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "personal_info.gender",
          label: "Gender",
          thClass: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "personal_info.age",
          label: "Age",
          class: "text-center"
        }
      ],
      expanded_rows: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onRowClicked(item) {
      const {
        expanded_rows
      } = this;
      const {
        uuid
      } = item;

      this.$set(expanded_rows, uuid, !expanded_rows[uuid]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/faker@5.5.3/dist/faker.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-pagination v-model="current_page" :per-page="per_page" :total-rows="total_rows">
  </b-pagination>

  <h4>Table is refresh with a new item every 5 seconds.</h4>
  <h6>Click on a row to expand the row</h6>
  <b-table :items="computed_users" :fields="fields" bordered hover striped :current-page="current_page" :per-page="per_page" @row-clicked="onRowClicked">
    <template #cell(avatar)="{ value }">
      <b-avatar :src="value"></b-avatar>
    </template>
    <template #cell(name)="{ item: { personal_info: { first_name, last_name } }}">
      {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}
    </template>
    <template #row-details="{ item }">
      <pre>{{ item }}</pre>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: I followed what you said and used set to add a _showDetails row after using an axios call to fetching the json.  it's working but not working.  It now blinks open and closed because of the table reload.  did I do something wrong or am I missing a piece?  We will e implementing websockets at some point, will that change the blinking behavior? (i've never worked with those)

Comment: correction, it stays open until 2 seconds have passed and then it closes and immediately re opens, repeating that pattern of behavior - essentially 'blinking'.  Can this be corrected? BTW Thanks for getting me closer!

Comment: decided that, real world situations, refreshing would occur less frequently than 2every 2 seconds so javascript setinterval() interval refresh time is now 60 seconds, axios pull occurs once a minute, definitely helps users examine child drop down information longer.  Reload of the b-table still causes the child to close and re open.  If anyone knows how to prevent this artifact, if anyone knows if using websockets to load the axios info (eliminating set interval) will solve the refresh issue, if anyone has any other suggestions, I am all ears

Comment: Are you setting `_showDetails` after or before updating the local data variable?

Comment: I moved everything to the store.  I update record the ID of the row the user wants to display in a store variable called 'showRecords'.  Before the commit of the table data to the store, I run through the incoming table data and check against 'showRecords' stored IDs,  if the row was marked as being displayed, i call Vue.set(tasklist[idx], "_showDetails", true); to add _showDetails to the record, and THEN add the taskList to the store.  It is after this that the component that displays the table accesses the taskList.  Works great, no blinking, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing you had blinking because your table was updated with the new data, and *then* you set the `_showDetails` afterwards. Glad you found a working solution. Feel free to accept the answer if you think it helped.